# Bitbucket Branch creation is copying files from other branches

Tags: git

I found out what is the deal with it, and what is that I'm getting confused with. Before, I would start repos from scratch without any code at all, so as I go, it progresses without any hiccups. Having to place files and overriding them in other branches give me a sense of weirdness as something was about to go wrong (and catching some sleep helped tremendously, I was unfortunately crunching hard).

I'll keep the original question here because it maybe help someone in the future.

---

I have been using `git` for years but apparently I'm missing something from a new update and after several tries, I'm quite confused with the new intent of the "last" `git` update. I'm not exactly sure if this is `Github` or `Bitbucket` exclusively, but I'm using the latter for work.

What I'm trying to do:

- When creating a new branch `git checkout -b [name]` to have a clean branch that doesn't have any files from any other branch

What is happening:

- Doesn't matter what I do, be it how I used to do it `git checkout -b [name]` or what seems the new way `git checkout --orphan [name]` the branches created *always* create branches that copy *all* files from the other branches.

This obviously defeats the purposes of branching, after all, files are copied and a tremendous mess happens, or I have to create folders and keep *all the other files* from other branches in different folders, which also defeats the purpose of `git`. What am I missing? Is it related to how I track files? I usually add all my files with `git add .` .

I have searched extensively (two hours) here on StackOverflow and Googled around, but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git checkout -b` command creates a new branch ***in your current repo, based on your current commit point.***

> As an aside, it doesn't *copy* the files per se, it just references the same objects as in the other branch, up until the point you change them in your new branch, at which point new objects will be created and the references changed.

If what you want is a new "thing" without any files in it (totally unrelated to what you currently have), that's really a brand new *repo* rather than a new branch. The command you need to look into for that is `git init`.

Or, if you *do* want a branch in the current repo but with no files in it, you'll probably need to use `git rm` to remove them from the new branch. However, that would be a rather unuasual use-case and you'd want to be *very* careful merging back to the original branch.

Your comment that "this obviously defeats the purposes of branching" indicates, at least to me, that you don't quite *understand* branching. Its point is to create a new branch *based on the old* where you can make changes and presumably bring those changes back into the original branch when they've been successfully developed/tested/validated/reviewed/whatever.

If you have a *different* view of branching, I'd be happy to hear it. That might help to clear up any misunderstanding.

---

By way of example, here's a before and after `git checkout -b newbranch` snapshot of `git log` (with the commit point compressed with `....`):

```
commit bed4....80d3 (HEAD -> oldbranch)
commit bed4....80d3 (HEAD -> newbranch, oldbranch)
```

This shows that the new branch is based on the old.

Comment: What in the actual hell... I _never_ had to remove files from another branch before. This doesn't make any sense at all?

Comment: @Luke, whether it makes any sense to *you* is not really relevant :-) That's the way `git checkout -b` works. It creates a new branch based on your current commit point. The doco says that it's equivalent to the `git branch` creation followed by checkout and the creation doco states it "creates a new branch head named <branchname> ***which points to the current HEAD***". In other words, as I said, based on your current commit point.

Comment: If, immediately after the `git checkout -b`, you run `git log`, you'll see the original branch and your new one are at exactly the same point. I've added a note to that effect to the answer.

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter if it makes sense _to me_, that's not what I said though, I was just referring to tracking and versioning. With that aside, I found out what is the deal with it, and what is that I'm getting confused with. Before, I would start repos from scratch without any code at all, so as I go, it progresses without any hiccups. Having to place files and overriding them in other branches give me a sense of weirdness as something was about to go wrong (and catching some sleep, I was unfortunately crunching hard. Thanks for the suggestions and patience engaging with the question.